# addrow undefined and remove button doesn't work in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Yesterday i post a question ask about my addrow button.Problem solved.
It run smoothly,but I have new problems.
Firstly, my delete button which I was used the remove()API is not working.
Secondly, everytime I reload the page, in the first row col5 will have the value : undefined
[image]
Once again, I appreciate every answer to this question.

```js
var table = null;
var arrData = [];
var arrDataPG = [];
arrData.push({
    STT: 1,
    id: 1,
    product_type: "",
    condition1: "",
    rebate: 0.0,
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitTable();
});

function InitTable() {
    if (table !== null && table !== undefined) {
        table.destroy();
    }
    table = $('#tableh').DataTable({
        data: arrData,
        "columns": [
            { "width": "25px" },
            { "width": "300px" },
            { "width": "300px" },
            { "width": "120px" },
            { "width": "200px" },
            { "width": "25px" },


        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                title: "STT",
                targets: 0,
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return (meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1);
                },
            },
            {
                title: "Loại sản phẩm*",
                targets: 1,
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<textarea style="width: 300px;" id="product_type' + data.id + '" type="text" onchange="ChangeProductType(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.product_type + '">' + data.product_type + '</textarea>';
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Điều kiện*",
                targets: 2,
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<textarea style="width: 300px;" id="condition1' + data.id + '" type="text" onchange="ChangeCondition1(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.condition1 + '">' + data.condition1 + '</textarea>';
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Rebate(%)*",
                targets: 3,
                data: null,
                width: "70",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<div><input id="rebate' + data.id + '" type="number" style="width: 70px;" onchange="ChangeRebate(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.rebate + '"></div>';

                }
            },
            {
                title: "Ghi chú",
                targets: 4,
                data: null,
                width: "250",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<textarea style="width:200px;" id="note' + data.id + '" type="text" onchange="ChangeNote(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.note + '">' + data.note + '</textarea>';

                }
            },
            {
                title: "",
                targets: 5,
                data: null,
                className: "dt-center",
                width: "70",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                   return '<div class="btn btn-danger removePG" style="cursor: pointer;font-size:25px;" onclick=removePG(\'' + data.id + '\')><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></div>'

                }
            },
        ],

    });
    table.columns.adjust().draw();
}

$('#addRow').on('click', function () {
    console.log(arrData.length);
    if (arrData != '') {
        var ida = arrData[0].id;
    } else {
        var ida = 1;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        if (arrData[i].id > ida) {
            ida = arrData[i].id;
        }
    };
    arrData.push({
        STT: ida + 1,
        id: ida + 1,
        product_type: "",
        condition1: "",
        rebate: 0.0,
        note: ""
    });
    if (table != null) {
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(arrData).draw();
    }
});
$('#tableh').on('click','.removePG', function () {
    var tableq = $('#table_h').DataTable();
    tableq
        .row($(this).parents('tr'))
        .remove()
        .draw();
});
function removePG(idc) {
    let id = parseInt(idc);
    if (arrData !== undefined) {
        var find = arrData.find(function (item) {
            return item.id === id;
        });
        if (find !== undefined) {
            arrData = arrData.filter(function (item, index) {
                return item.id !== id;
            });
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="tableh" class="cell-border hover" style="width:100%"></table>
            
<button style="width: 86px;" id="addRow" class="btn btn-success add">Addrow<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60bf89e922.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: See near `arrData.push` you don't have note property in that object.  You haven't defined `removePG()` function anywhere

Comment: "*my delete button .. not working"* - and what's the error message tell you when you click it?

Comment: I add the **removePG()** function but it not delete right after I click the button :'(

Comment: Your removePG() function just returns a boolean - how's that intended to remove a row?

Comment: Can you explain more 
Cause i have a function that select the table and when I click the button it will delete the whole <tr> that include the button

Comment: You have a button with `onclick=removePG(id)` that `removePG` is essentially `function removePG { return null; }`  => onclick=null.   Does nothing.  Inside the function you have `arrData = ...` but you do nothing with that arrData.  You need to refresh the table by calling the datatables API.

Comment: All problems solved.
Thank you guys a bunch  

Comment: As noted in first comment above.   You generate your HTML as `value="'+data.note+'"` - but your `arrData.push({ ...` doesn't push a `note` property.  `arrData.push({ STT: 1, note:"it's a note", id:1, ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thankyou once again for your enthusiasm